# Groupby function in pandas dataframe of Python does not seem to work

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a table with various information (e.g. energy supply, proportion of renewable energy supply) to 15 countries. I have to create a dataframe with information on continent level to the number of countries on each continent and the mean, standard deviation and sum of the population of the respective countries on those continents. The dataframe consists of the data of the table mentioned above. My problem is that I can't seem to aggregate the data on continent level after mapping the 15 countries to their respective continent. I have to use a predefined dictionary to solve this task. Could you please help me in this? Please find my Code below:

```
def answer_eleven():

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

Top15 = answer_one()
Top15['Country Name'] = Top15.index

ContinentDict  = {'China':'Asia', 
                  'United States':'North America', 
                  'Japan':'Asia', 
                  'United Kingdom':'Europe', 
                  'Russian Federation':'Europe', 
                  'Canada':'North America', 
                  'Germany':'Europe', 
                  'India':'Asia',
                  'France':'Europe', 
                  'South Korea':'Asia', 
                  'Italy':'Europe', 
                  'Spain':'Europe', 
                  'Iran':'Asia',
                  'Australia':'Australia', 
                  'Brazil':'South America'}

Top15['Continent'] = pd.Series(ContinentDict)
#Top15['size'] = Top15['Country'].count()
Top15['Population'] = (Top15['Energy Supply'] / Top15['Energy Supply per Capita'])
#columns_to_keep = ['Continent', 'Population']
#Top15 = Top15[columns_to_keep]
#Top15 = Top15.set_index('Continent').groupby(level=0)['Population'].agg({'sum': np.sum})
Top15.set_index(['Continent'], inplace = True)
Top15['size'] = Top15.groupby(['Continent'])['Country Name'].count()
Top15['sum'] = Top15.groupby(['Continent'])['Population'].sum()
Top15['mean'] = Top15.groupby(['Continent'])['Population'].mean()
Top15['std'] = Top15.groupby(['Continent'])['Population'].std()
columns_to_keep = ['size', 'sum', 'mean', 'std']
Top15 = Top15[columns_to_keep]
#Top15['Continent Name'] = Top15.index
#Top15.groupby(['Continent'], level = 0, sort = True)['size'].count()

return Top15.iloc[:5]
answer_eleven()
```

Comment: Can you `print(df.head(10))` along with expected output? Not sure from your code what the problem is.

Comment: Does it make sense to set Continent as the index?

Comment: @roganjosh: The continent is already in the index. See line "Top15.set_index(['Continent'], inplace = True)"

Comment: Sorry, the phrasing of my comment was unclear. I'm suggesting that I don't think it makes sense, I was wondering why you did it.

Comment: I thought it is necessary to do so for the groupby function to work.

Comment: @COLDSPEED: The expected output is data aggregated on continent level. The output I get is data on country lvel (e.g. 2 rows for North America, 5 for Asia and 6 for Europe in the table instead of just one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) for aggregate by dictionary:

```
def answer_eleven():

    Top15 = answer_one()
    ContinentDict  = {'China':'Asia',
                      'United States':'North America',
                      'Japan':'Asia',
                      'United Kingdom':'Europe',
                      'Russian Federation':'Europe',
                      'Canada':'North America',
                      'Germany':'Europe',
                      'India':'Asia',
                      'France':'Europe',
                      'South Korea':'Asia',
                      'Italy':'Europe',
                      'Spain':'Europe',
                      'Iran':'Asia',
                      'Australia':'Australia',
                      'Brazil':'South America'}

    Top15['Population'] = (Top15['Energy Supply'] / Top15['Energy Supply per Capita'])
    Top15 = Top15.groupby(ContinentDict)['Population'].agg(['size','sum','mean','std'])
    return Top15
```

---

```
df = answer_eleven()
print (df)

                        sum          mean           std  size
Country Name                                                 
Asia           2.771785e+09  9.239284e+08  6.913019e+08     3
Australia      2.331602e+07  2.331602e+07           NaN     1
Europe         4.579297e+08  7.632161e+07  3.464767e+07     6
North America  3.528552e+08  1.764276e+08  1.996696e+08     2
South America  2.059153e+08  2.059153e+08           NaN     1
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I just tried it and I get an error message: "KeyError: "['size' 'sum' 'mean' 'std'] not in index"

Comment: Do you use `Top15.columns = Top15.columns.droplevel(0)` ?

Comment: Yes, I used it. This is how the bottom of my code looks like now(unfortunately we are not allowed to use the print function):                                                                                             Top15 =  Top15.groupby(level=0).agg({'Country Name':'count', 
                                         'Population':['sum','mean','std']})
    
    Top15.columns = Top15.columns.droplevel(0)
    
    Top15.set_index(['sum', 'mean', 'std', 'count'], dtype='object', inplace = True)
    
    return Top15
answer_eleven()

Comment: only remove `Top15.set_index(['sum', 'mean', 'std', 'count'], dtype='object', inplace = True)`, it is only for check ;)

Comment: I dremoved it but I still get the same error message (KeyError: "['size' 'sum' 'mean' 'std'] not in index")

Comment: @eszter - I change answer a bit, instead `.agg({'Country Name':'count', ` is used `.agg({'Country Name':'size', ` , I believe now it working nice.

Comment: I edited the code, but I still get the same error message. :-(

Comment: So there is another problem, can you share your file for create dataframe?

Comment: How can i share the file with you?

Comment: |Send me your file with your all code to my email in my profile.

Comment: Just sent you a mail. Thank you very much! :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jezrael!!! I just tried your edited code and it works! I am very grateful to you!